# Python GUI using Kivy. Cannot save figures when running .exe file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, exe

Using Python and Kivy I have created an interface. When I run the code in Pycharm everything goes smoothly, but when I run the .exe file of the application, the code crashes just before saving some figures.

In the code, at some point, I create some figures and I save them in one folder (/Results_plots) inside the main folder where the project is located (/main). The figures are saved using:

```
plt.savefig(f"Results_plots/Comparison/figure1")
```

I have also tried without succeeding:

```
basepath=os.path.abspath(str(f"Results_plots/Comparison"))

plt.figure(os.path.join(basepath, f"figure1"))
```

Extra information that might help:

- I created the exe file by using:

```
pyinstaller main_script.py
```

Then I modify the .spec and I run "pyinstaller main_script.spec"

- The main_script.py of the project interconnects with other scripts and reads files from other folders inside the main folder. This seems to work properly when running the .exe file
- kivy version: v1.11.1
- python version: Python 3.7.4
- pyinstaller version: 4.0
- matplotlib version: 3.1.3

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If not, try running the `.exe` from a command prompt and look for an error message there.

Comment: I run the `.exe` from a command prompt. In the `.py` code I introduced a lot of "prints" so that I can see where it crashes. It crashes just before saving the first figure, without giving back any error message. However I found a partial solution. I run it in a virtual environment and now it works fine. I honestly don't understand why though. I will update the question with this partial solution

Comment: Ok, I continue having the same issue. In my computer when I run it in a virtual environment it is fine, but when I try it in another computer (inside another virtual environment) I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% on this but I've had similar issues with iOS. The trick is to save your photos in the file system which the application can use to store additional data.

On a Windows computer this directory is `%APPDATA%/<app_name>`

Thankfully the brains behind Kivy have created a convenient property of the App class that returns a path to the correct directory called `user_data_dir`.

Saving the photos to `App.user_data_dir` solved my problem. Maybe it'll work for you? Let me know.